# Finding formula for a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am not sure how to find a formula for the following series.

$\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8},\frac{15}{16},\frac{31}{32}$

I am thinking it might be $\frac{2N-1}{N^2}$ for the numerator but this does hold on n=3

another series I am trying to find is

$2,0,2,0,2$

I kow $-1^n=-1$

But I a not sure what this could be

Comment: HINT: For the 1st series note that the numerator is always 1 less than the denominator and the denominator is a power of 2.

Comment: I see so it is $2^{n}-1/2^n$

Comment: Please be careful with parentheses.  $2N-1/N^2=2N-\frac 1{N^2}\neq \frac {2N-1}{N^2}$.  Clearly you mean the latter, but often it is not so clear.  In your recent comment, the $-1$ should not be in the exponent.

Comment: Is there any way to know what pattern it is using a formula because I am bad at seeing these patterns.....

Comment: the another series $1 - ?? = 0 \text{ or 2}$ ??

Comment: the series is 2,0,2,0,2 like that

Comment: the other way you can write it up as $1 + 1, 1-1, 1 + 1, 1 - 1, ....$

Comment: yes you are right mr.x

Comment: so I am think it would be $1^n+1$ that would work for the first but not the second

Comment: check it [yourself](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B1+-+%28-1%29%5E%28n%2B1%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+10%7D%5D)

Comment: It's not a series, it's a sequence.  A series is a sum of numbers (usually infinitely many).  You're not adding anything.  I'm very surprised no one has pointed out this mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant for the nth term in the first case to be $\dfrac {2n-1}{2^n}$, your close, but let's try $$\dfrac{2^n - 1}{2^n}\quad ?$$

For the second, how about $$(1 - (-1)^n)\quad ?$$

Comment: Yes that works perfectly

Comment: thanks hmm I guess it takes practice to be able to see a formula from a series...

Comment: Your welcome, Fernando. Yes, indeed, practice with all sorts of series helps you develop a lot more intuition for "pattern finding".

Comment: Also, just to be clear: recall that $(-1)^n$ is $-1$ for *odd* $n$, but $1$ for *even* $n$. This makes sense because every even $n$ can be expressed as $2k$, so $(-1)^n = (-1)^{2k} = \Big((-1)^2\Big)^k = 1^k = 1$ where $k \in \mathbb N, k\geq 0, 1$, depending on indexing. A similar argument can be made for odd $n$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The numerator is increasing by $2^n$ and the denominator by $2^n$.

But you have a number less on the top...so....$2^n-1$ could be the numerator perhaps? $2^n$ the denominator?